# Why the object is not null?

Tags: java

```
public class C

{
   public void foo (D d)
   {
     System.out.println("cd");
   }
}

public class D extends C
{
  public void foo(C c)
  {
      System.out.println("dc");
  }

  public void foo(D d)
  {
    System.out.println("dd");
  }
}

public class Driver
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      C cd = new D();
      D dd = (D)cd;
      dd.foo(dd);
   }
}
```

Why does it work and the objects are not null, i would have think that cd and dd are null because of the default constructor?
Is this an "empty" object that only has an adrress in the heap space?
I need further explanation please, thank you.

Comment: Why would they be null? A constructor won't return a null. That would defeat the purpose of the constructor.

Comment: I think default constructor implies that the object is created, however the object attributes will be set to null.

Comment: When you talk of an "attribute", what do you mean?

Comment: This object has no instance variables it just has an address to an empty location in the memory, i read about default value of the default constructor and object refernce should be null don't they?

Comment: @st379 No. If the class you're instantiating has fields, the default constructor won't initialize them, so they'll be null. The constructor won't return a null instance though.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly if one of the instance variable is an object it will be null, an int 0,...   But in my case it is an "empty" object with an address in the heap space?